# how can i use tabulator\whitespace in JTextPane using html?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I wish to use some tabspace in my JTextPane using html, how can i do it ?
I tried the Java way with putting \t, however that seems not to work.

this is my code:

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");
String ausgabe = "hello world";
HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument) pane.getStyledDocument();
doc.insertAfterEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(doc.getLength()),"<b>"+ausgabe"+"<br></b>");
```

Comment: `doc.insertAfterEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(doc.getLength()),"<b>"+ausgabe"+"<br></b>");` alerted by the forum code formatting, I suspect that won't compile since it has unbalanced `"`.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you can also insert 4 times the character `&nbsp;`

Comment: This is not the same as a tab. If you follow the line of text with another line such as `"Hi\teverybody"`, a proper tab should ensure that the "world" in the first line, and the "everybody" in the second line align perfectly (depending on the setting of tab stops, which is usually 8 characters).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, HTML does not display formatting such as indentation, tabs, etc. You can check that in a plain HTML file in a browser.

However, there is one circumstance where it does - in a *preformatted* block. That is, with the tag `<pre>`.

So try changing that last line to:

```
doc.insertAfterEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(doc.getLength()),"<pre>"+ausgabe+"</pre>");
```

Note that the font used in preformatted blocks is usually fixed-width (e.g. Courier or a similar font).